# Android Can you add a widget inside another widget?

Tags: android

Since Widgets are Views of sorts I was wondering if you can add and position one widget inside another.
For example could you add a EditText to a button?  and have the button contain say one or more EditTexts inside it?  Would this be possible (not that its a recommended way but could it be done). and if so how would I do this?  Its important that I not only be able to add the other widget but also size and position it within the other widget.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you CAN'T achieve this, since widgets can only be put on a layout. You can position a widget on top of another widget if you will use a relative layout.